# How to send single email from spreadsheet to people whom names are repeated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet of the following format. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-GwqlPofB7P4g2o3DbZKtdu5pMXvnQdgRDlhoyVijeg/edit?usp=sharing

I want to send mail to individual owners (people) including 2 tables, 1st table to include all the actionable that are not completed and the close that has been crossed, and the 2nd table to include all the actionable that are yet to be completed but closed date has not been crossed.

For eg :- Expected mail to be sent to Name 1 is

Hi, following tasks are delayed:
Table of showing tasks which are delayed
------ |||including Tasks 3 and Task 9|||

The following tasks are yet to be completed:
table showing tasks which are not completed but also not delayed.
--------------|||Task 1 and Task 6|||

---

---

I have created an app-script to send email to a person when only 1 persons task are mention are 1 sheet. I am not able to do so with multiple people being mentioned in the same sheet multiple times.

```js
function SendMail() {
// GETTING VALUES FROM SPREADSHEET
     //Selecting the sheet
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("name"); 
    var startRow = 4;  // First row of data to process
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-3; // Number of rows to process
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn()); // Selecting the range of data
    var data = dataRange.getValues(); // Get all values in the range.

    //Creating Today's Date
    // Date String in required format
    var today_string = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT+05:30', 'MM/dd/yyyy'); 
    var today = new Date(today_string)
    today.setHours(0,0,0,0)
    //Logger.log(today);

    //Creating an Empty Array in which values will be added 
    var delayed = [];
    var pending =[];
  
    // Initiating For Loop
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
      var row = data[i];          // Creating all the rows
      var close_date_string = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[4]),'GMT+05:30','MM/dd/yyyy'); // Close Date String
      var close_date = new Date(close_date_string)          //Close_Date, (Date Value)
      close_date.setHours(0,0,0,0)

      // Putting condition to fill the delayed array 
      if (close_date < today && row[5].toString().match("Completed") != "Completed") {   
        var delayed_text = {};
        delayed_text.actionable = row[1];
        delayed_text.start_date = row[3] ?
                        Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[3]),'GMT+05:30','MMMM dd, yyyy') :
                        "-";
        delayed_text.close_date = row[4] ?
                        Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[4]),'GMT+05:30','MMMM dd, yyyy') :
                        "-";
        delayed.push(delayed_text)
      }

      // Putting conditions to fill the Pending array
      if (close_date >= today && row[5].toString().match("Completed") != "Completed") {
        var pending_text = {};
        pending_text.actionable = row[1];
        pending_text.start_date = row[3] ?
                      Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[3]),'GMT+05:30','MMMM dd, yyyy') :
                      "-";
        pending_text.close_date = row[4] ?
                      Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[4]),'GMT+05:30','MMMM dd, yyyy') :
                      "-";
        pending.push(pending_text)
      }
    } 

    //Getting HTML Table for Delayed 
    var delayed_template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Delayed.html");
    delayed_template.delayed = delayed;
    var delayed_table = delayed_template.evaluate().getContent();  


    //Getting HTML Table for pending
    var pending_template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Pending.html");
    pending_template.pending = pending;
    var pending_table = pending_template.evaluate().getContent();  
    //Logger.log(pending_table)

    
    //Making an empty variable message to add tables to it on basis of condition
    var message = ""
    
    // Making conditions to add table to message content
    if (Object.keys(delayed).length && Object.keys(pending).length) {
        message = ("Hi Sir,\n" + delayed_table + pending_table) ;
    
    } else if (Object.keys(delayed).length) {
        message = ("Hi Sir,\n" + delayed_table) ;
    
    } else if (Object.keys(pending).length) {
         message = ("Hi Sir,\n" + pending_table)  ;
    
    } else {
        message = ""  ;
    }
 
    // SENDING MAIL
    if (message) {
    //Logger.log("sent")
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "email",
        subject: "Actionable Status",
        htmlBody: message
      })
    
    } // closing if statement

  } //closing SendEmail
```

---

How to create an apps-cript that can work with the above sheet?

Comment: The script is populating the array and then adding the values to html table. This app-script is running for another sheet. I have provided this for reference to what I have done. I am not able to figure out the logic to be used to create message for individual owners and sending them the message.

Comment: @MikeSteelson the criteria for delayed is status != completed and date < today(),
and for pending is status != completed & date >= today().

Comment: At this stage I can't distinguish Name 1 and Name 10, but I think that in real life you won't have this problem. If not, I can continue working on it tomorrow.

Comment: I have to automatically send the mail to all the Names. and their emails will be present in another sheet. 
Thanx alot for your Help!!

Comment: @MikeSteelson Thanx a lot for the code but it is not solving the problem of sending the mail people only including the tasks in which there name is mentioned, but it is helpful. Also can you upload the previous code as well it was very helpful as well.

Comment: no problem to update the code. However could you explain with more details what is wrong? Thx in advance.

Comment: you will receive in your mailbox the result of the test I have done just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function sendEmails() {
  var [, ...rows] = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2').getDataRange().getValues()
  rows.forEach(r => sendEmail(r[0], r[1]))
}

function sendEmail(name, email) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  var [headers, ...rows] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var today = new Date()
  //delayed
  var delayed = rows.filter(r => (getAllNames(r[3]).indexOf(name) != -1 && r[5] != 'Completed' && r[7] < today))
  delayed.forEach(function (r) {
    r[6] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(r[6]), 'GMT+05:30', 'MMMM dd, yyyy')
    r[7] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(r[7]), 'GMT+05:30', 'MMMM dd, yyyy')
  })
  //pending
  var pending = rows.filter(r => (getAllNames(r[3]).indexOf(name) != -1 && r[5] != 'Completed' && r[7] >= today))
  pending.forEach(function (r) {
    r[6] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(r[6]), 'GMT+05:30', 'MMMM dd, yyyy')
    r[7] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(r[7]), 'GMT+05:30', 'MMMM dd, yyyy')
  })
  //message
  var message = (delayed.length > 0 ? tableHTML([headers], delayed) : '') +
    '<br><br>' + (pending.length > 0 ? tableHTML([headers], pending) : '')
  if (delayed.length > 0 || pending.length > 0) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: "Actionable Status",
      htmlBody: message
    })
  }
}

function tableHTML(headers, data) {
  var tableformat = 'cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ccc';
  var header = headers.map(h => '<tr><th>' + h.join('</th><th>') + '</th></tr>')
  var rows = data.map(h => '<tr><td>' + h.join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>')
  return '<table ' + tableformat + ' ">\n' + header.join('\n') + rows.join('\n') + '</table>'
}

function getAllNames(coop) {
  var names = []
  coop.split('&').forEach(function (name) {
    names.push(name.trim())
  })
  return (names.sort())
}
```

[image]